# Como convierto un int a un string?

Tags: c#

Quiero convertir un valor de tipo int a un string para mostrarlo en un textbox como seria la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: un int se puede mostrar tal cual en un textbox, en todo caso si pones nombre_variable.ToString() ya lo tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Espero te sirva:

```
string miString = miEntero.ToString();
```

Comment: si me sirvió gracias

Comment: @EdwinCasco recuerda revisar [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Hay varias preguntas tuyas sin ser aceptadas. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;

bool result=Int32.TryParse("160519",number);
```

Devuelve true si lo convierte bien, sino false. El valor convertido a integer, lo guarda en el segundo parametro (number en este caso)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
//Tienes el número en tu variable de tipo int.

int valorNumerico = 5;

//Agregar a la variable texto el valor numérico y le agregas una cadena vacía "".

string texto = valorNumerico + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

De int a string

```
MiString = Convert.ToString(5);
```

De string a int

```
MiInt = Convert.ToInt32("5");
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el metodo statico `int.TryParse` donde acepta 2 parametros: el primero es el string y el segundo es la variable  que contendra el valor convertido:

```
int numero;
if(Int32.TryParse("160519", out numero)){
   Console.WriteLine("El valor convertido es {0}", numero);
}
else{
  Console.WriteLine("El valor no es un numero");
}
```

En caso de que te lo preguntes, [`out`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) te permite enviar la variable numero por referencia, no por valor lo que hace que pueda ser modificado dentro del metodo y el valor reflejarse cuando termina la ejecucion del mismo.